# Selenium Maven Java Automated Test problem with run

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automated-tests

I got problem with selenium, it's weird.
I've written a few test cases and running it using Maven.
Every test returns positive result only when running in isolation. When I run all tests using Maven together some of then pass and some not...

If someone know how to fix it I'll be grateful!

Comment: You're probably reusing your driver between tests and they're state-dependent.

Comment: For each test I'm creating new driver but I'm not closing it, it can be a main problem ?

Comment: It might be a problem with opened driver instances. Try to add teardown after test, that gonna quit() or close() a driver - depends of what driver You use for Your tests.

Comment: please share some more insights on the maven console and result. Is there any specific tests that are failing always, is there any pattern you have noticed.

Comment: Now it's ok, the main problem was that I'm not closing the driver between each test :)